# Prevent a white space in the beginning of a input

Tags: javascript

Basically I been trying to design a js script that prevents a white space character from existing from the beginning of a input I been trying to figure this out but no luck so far. Most working examples of this subject is based in jQuery I can't find any working examples `in pure java script`. **No jQuery pure Javascript** code advice.

```js
//??
```

```html
<input id='noWhiteSpaceAtTheStart' type='text'>
```

Comment: Are you referring to the small padding that comes before the input element or within the textbox ? because I dont see any white space within textbox

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try the RegEx `/^\s/` to match white space at the start of the string. Then simply set the input value to blank (`''`) if the condition is true:

```js
function validate(input){
  if(/^\s/.test(input.value))
    input.value = '';
}
```

```html
<input id='noWhiteSpaceAtTheStart' oninput="validate(this)" type='text'/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let yourInput = document.getElementById('noWhiteSpaceAtTheStart');
yourInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
    yourInput.value = yourInput.value ? yourInput.value.trimStart() : '' 
})
```

```html
<input id='noWhiteSpaceAtTheStart' type='text'/>
```

This should do the trick:

on input event, if `input.value` is `undefined` (testing for falsy is enough) set an empty string, just to make sure we don't call methods on an undefined object...

Otherwise, return the same value after calling trimStart on it!

EDIT: First answer I was suggesting using the `change` event - but that triggers only for "submits": clicking outside, pressing tab, and so on... The `input` event instead triggers at **every** edit.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var inp =  document.querySelector('#noWhiteSpaceAtTheStart');
inp.addEventListener("keypress",function(e){
var key = e.keyCode;
if(key === 32){
e.preventDefault();
return false;
}
})
```

```html
<input id='noWhiteSpaceAtTheStart' type='text'>
```

Comment: using e.preventDefault to prevent its default behavior and prevent white space on keypress

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following js function

```
 <script> 
                    function NoSpaces() { 
                            if (event.keyCode == 32) { 
                                    event.returnValue = false; 
                                    return false; 
                            } 
                    } 
            </script>
```

and call it on onkeypress event in the textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="yourtextbox" runat="server" onkeypress="return NoSpaces()"></asp:TextBox>
```